# How do you disable awesome_print once enabled in IRB or rails console?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, irb, awesomeprint

I have awesome_print configured to be my default formatter in IRB (using `AwesomePrint.irb!` in my .irbrc) and while this is normally awesome, I want to turn it off sometimes. Anybody know how to from a running IRB/Rails console?

Comment: What are you using to utilize `awesome_print` gem?  Avoid using `ap` in IRB for example, then you simply don't use it.  What does your `.irbrc` file look like?  or is it simply a `require 'awesome_print'` entry?

Comment: @vgoff: My .irbrc has "require 'awesome_print'; AwesomePrint.irb!" which replaces all my IRB output with AwesomePrint formatting. That's what I want to disable from time to time without restarting the session.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can paste this in to you terminal to reset it back to what it was originally if you like:

```
IRB::Irb.class_eval do
  def output_value # :nodoc:
    printf @context.return_format, @context.inspect_last_value
  end
end
```

or you can go whole hog and monkey patch AwesomePrint:

```
module AwesomePrint
  def self.un_irb!
    IRB::Irb.class_eval do
      def output_value # :nodoc:
        printf @context.return_format, @context.inspect_last_value
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then just call it whenever you want: `AwesomePrint.un_irb!`

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid it was something like this. Maybe I'll add a feature request to AwesomePrint to add this functionality.